# Creating Raster from Array using GDAL Results in Stripes

Tags: python, gdal, array

I am using a template raster to create another raster with the same resolution/projection/extent from an array. The original raster looks good, but the new raster results in stripes.

```
ds = gdal.Open(template_raster)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = band.ReadAsArray()
[rows,cols] = arr.shape
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_ds=driver.Create(output_raster,cols,rows,1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
out_band.WriteArray(input_array)
out_ds.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
out_ds.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
wkt = ds.GetProjection()
srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
out_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
out_band.FlushCache()
del input_array
del out_band
out_ds = None
del ds
```

[image: Output Raster With Stripes]

Comment: I do not see `input_array` defined in your code. Did you mean to write `arr` or are you referencing another array that did not show in your code? Furthermore, why are you setting the output raster projection twice? `out_ds.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())` gets the job done so you would not need to create a spatial reference, import the wkt and then set the projection again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems possible that you have an old variable for the array. I cleaned up your code a little by referring directly to `arr`.

```
ds = gdal.Open(template_raster)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = band.ReadAsArray()
[rows,cols] = arr.shape
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_ds=driver.Create(output_raster,cols,rows,1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
out_band.WriteArray(arr)
out_ds.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
out_ds.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
out_band.FlushCache()
del input_array
del out_band
out_ds = None
del ds
```